# Trouble creating query in MongoDB with subquery

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```js
{
  "id": "02741544",
  "items": [{
    "item": "A"
  }]
}, {
  "id": "02472691",
  "items": [{
    "item": "A"
  }, {
    "item": "B"
  }, {
    "item": "C"
  }]
}, {

  "id": "01316523",
  "items": [{
    "item": "A"
  }, {
    "item": "B"
  }]
}, {
  "id": "01316526",
  "items": [{
    "item": "A"
  }, {
    "item": "B"
  }]
}, {
  "id": "01316529",
  "items": [{
    "item": "A"
  }, {
    "item": "D"
  }]
},
```

I'm trying to craft a query that will give me an output that looks like this:

```js
{
  "item": "A",
  "ids": [{
    "id": "02741544"

  }, {
    "id": "02472691"

  }, {
    "id": "01316523"

  }, {
    "id": "01316526"

  }, {
    "id": "01316529"

  }]
}, {
  "item": "B",
  "ids": [{
    "id": "02472691"

  }, {
    "id": "01316523"

  }, {
    "id": "01316526"

  }]
}, {
  "item": "C",
  "ids": [{
    "id": "02472691"

  }]
}, {
  "item": "D",
  "ids": [{
    "id": "02472691"

  }]
},
```

Basically, I'm trying to get the distinct items from the item array in the object, and then returning an array of ids for each obj that has that item in it's item array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better use the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) in which you need to run an operation that consists of the following pipeline steps (in the given order):

1. **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** - This initial step will flatten the `items` array i.e. it produces a copy of each document per array entry. This is necessary for processing the documents further down the pipeline as "denormalised" documents which you can aggregate as groups.
2. **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** - This will group the flattened documents by the `item` subdocument key and create the `ids` list by using the **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push)** accumulator operator.

**-- UPDATE --**

As @AminJ pointed out in the comments, if `items` can have duplicate item values and you don't want duplicate ids in the result you can use **[`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)** instead of **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push)**

The following example demonstrates this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([   
    { "$unwind": "$items" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$items.item",
            "ids": { 
                "$push": { "id": "$id" } /* or use 
                "$addToSet": { "id": "$id" } if you don't want duplicate ids */                    
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
{
    "_id" : "A",
    "ids" : [ 
        { "id" : "02741544" }, 
        { "id" : "02472691" }, 
        { "id" : "01316523" }, 
        { "id" : "01316526" }, 
        { "id" : "01316529" }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "B",
    "ids" : [ 
        { "id" : "02472691" }, 
        { "id" : "01316523" }, 
        { "id" : "01316526" }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "C",
    "ids" : [ 
        { "id" : "02472691" }
    ]
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : "D",
    "ids" : [ 
        { "id" : "01316529" }
    ]
}
```

---

The result from an [**`aggregate()`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) function is a cursor to the documents produced by the final stage of the aggregation pipeline operation. So if you want the results in an array you can use the cursor's **[`toArray()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/#cursor.toArray)** method which returns an array that contains all the documents from it.

For example:

```
var pipeline = [    
        { "$unwind": "$items" },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$items.item",
                "ids": { 
                    "$push": { "id": "$id" } /* or use 
                    "$addToSet": { "id": "$id" } if you don't want duplicate ids */                    
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    results = db.collection.aggregate(pipeline).toArray();

printjson(results);
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning if `items` can have duplicate `item` values and you don't want duplicate ids in the result you can use `addToSet` instead of `push`.

Comment: This gives the desired output as far as content goes, but it doesn't return the results as an array of objects. How is that accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using an aggregation pipeline:

```
    db.col.aggregate([
        {
            $unwind: "$items"
        },
        {
            $project: {
                id: 1,
                item: "$items.item"
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$item",
                ids: {
                    $push: "$id"
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```